# `gganimate` fps is not the same as specified

Tags: r, ggplot2, png, frame-rate, gganimate

I am trying to output an animation using R and `gganimate`. I want an animation of 3 columns and 10 rows, each cell of which is lighted up one by one to show all row combinations. I think the code and animation below explain it.

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
library(magrittr)

scn_to_plot <- 1000

lst_block <- lapply(seq(10), function(i) {
  return(c(list(rep(0:2, each = 3**(10-i), times = 3**(i-1))), list(rep(1:3, each = 3**(10-i), times = 3**(i-1)))))
}) %>% do.call(c, .) %>% set_names(paste0(rep(paste0("p", 1:10), each = 2), rep(c("x1", "x2"), times = 10))) %>% as.data.table
lst_block[lst_block == 1] <- 1/3
lst_block[lst_block == 2] <- 2/3
lst_block[lst_block == 3] <- 1
lst_block[, paste0(rep(paste0("p", 1:10), each = 2), rep(c("y1", "y2"), times = 10)) := list(
  0.9, 1, 0.8, 0.9, 0.7, 0.8, 0.6, 0.7, 0.5, 0.6, 0.4, 0.5, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 0, 0.1
)]
lst_block[, scnN := seq(.N)]

p_bs <- ggplot(lst_block[1:scn_to_plot], aes(x = p1x1, y = p1y1)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(0, 1)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 0, "cm"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
p_bs %<>%
  add(geom_rect(aes(xmin = p1x1, xmax = p1x2, ymin = p1y1, ymax = p1y2), size = 0, fill = "#ff0000", alpha = 0.25)) %>%
  add(geom_rect(aes(xmin = p2x1, xmax = p2x2, ymin = p2y1, ymax = p2y2), size = 0, fill = "#ff0000", alpha = 0.25)) %>%
  add(geom_rect(aes(xmin = p3x1, xmax = p3x2, ymin = p3y1, ymax = p3y2), size = 0, fill = "#ff0000", alpha = 0.25)) %>%
  add(geom_rect(aes(xmin = p4x1, xmax = p4x2, ymin = p4y1, ymax = p4y2), size = 0, fill = "#ff0000", alpha = 0.25)) %>%
  add(geom_rect(aes(xmin = p5x1, xmax = p5x2, ymin = p5y1, ymax = p5y2), size = 0, fill = "#ff0000", alpha = 0.25)) %>%
  add(geom_rect(aes(xmin = p6x1, xmax = p6x2, ymin = p6y1, ymax = p6y2), size = 0, fill = "#ff0000", alpha = 0.25)) %>%
  add(geom_rect(aes(xmin = p7x1, xmax = p7x2, ymin = p7y1, ymax = p7y2), size = 0, fill = "#ff0000", alpha = 0.25)) %>%
  add(geom_rect(aes(xmin = p8x1, xmax = p8x2, ymin = p8y1, ymax = p8y2), size = 0, fill = "#ff0000", alpha = 0.25)) %>%
  add(geom_rect(aes(xmin = p9x1, xmax = p9x2, ymin = p9y1, ymax = p9y2), size = 0, fill = "#ff0000", alpha = 0.25)) %>%
  add(geom_rect(aes(xmin = p10x1, xmax = p10x2, ymin = p10y1, ymax = p10y2), size = 0, fill = "#ff0000", alpha = 0.25))
p_bs %<>% add(transition_manual(scnN))

anim_save("plot_combn.gif", animation = p_bs, nframes = 600, fps = 60, bg = "transparent")
```

[image]

I am encountering two problems:

- No matter how I change the `fps` (the last line) (I also tried using `options(gganimate.fps = xx)`, it seems that the fps of the final output gif file is fixed at somewhere like 10.
- The background cannot be changed to transparent even I have specified it for the `png` device. (I need to embed the resultant gif file in powerpoint presentation, but the outcome always has a white background.)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: from the helppage of `?anim_save`, it seems you are not passing the correct arguments. In fact i get an error: *Error in anim_save("plot_combn.gif", animation = p_bs, nframes = 600,  : 
  unused arguments (nframes = 600, fps = 60, bg = "transparent")* (although maybe we are using different versions?? : v‘0.9.9.9999’)

Comment: @user20650 Same version as you. Not sure why. `nframes` and `fps` are arguments passed to `animate()`, while `bg` is argument passed to the device (`png()` in this case). No such error on my side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the maximum allowed fps value is 50. If you go above that (like in your case 60) it will go back to the default 10 without any error messages. So try set the fps to 50!